# Sufficient and necessary conditions for decomposing the sum of random variables

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, calculus-of-variations

Given two $n$-tuple vectors $\vec{\alpha}=(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)$ and
$\vec{h}=(h_1,\cdots,h_n)$, where $h_i\ge0$, $\sum_{i=1}^nh_i=1$, and $\alpha_i\in(0,1)$, we consider a random variable $S$ on the interval $[0,1]$. My question is how to find the sufficient and necessary conditions for decomposability of $S$ into $n$ random variables $X_1,~X_2,~\cdots,X_n$ on $[0,1]$ satisfying
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n h_iX_i=S,~\text{and}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[X_i\right]=\alpha_i.
\end{equation}

**Please note that the parameters $h_i$ and $\alpha_i$ are given at the start.**

---

Two trivial necessary conditions are given as follows:

1. $\mathbb{E}\left[S\right]=\sum_{i=1}^nh_i\alpha_i$;
2. $\mathbb{P}\left[X_1=\cdots=X_n=0|S=0\right]=1$ and $\mathbb{P}\left[X_1=\cdots=X_n=1|S=1\right]=1$.

Comment: independent $X_i$?

Comment: The problem is meaningless, unless you add the condition that $X_j$ are independent. With this condition, there is an extensive theory: see Linnik, Ostrovskii, Decomposition of random variables and vectors, AMS 1977.

Comment: @ Dieter Kadelka Not necessarily independent.

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko: I think this question is not easy even without the assumption of independent $X_i$. I found the sufficient and necessary condition in the case of $n=2$, i.e. $\mathbb{E}\left[ (S-h_1)\mathbf{1}\left(S-h_1\right)\right]\le (1-h_1)\alpha_{2}$ (the ordering of descending $\alpha_i$ is adopted), while the case of $n\ge3$ seems intractable

Comment: @Ryan Chen: I did not write that it is easy. Several books are written on this question, one of them I cited. But if you don't require independence, you can just write $X_j=S/h_j$ and obtain a required decomposition.

Comment: To the OP: can you clarify if the $h_i$ and $\alpha_i$ are given at the start of the problem? I think many of the comments/answers you have received are reading your question as if it says: "given a RV $S$ and some fixed $n$, when can I decompose ..." whereas perhaps you mean "given a RV $S$ and $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n \in (0,1)$, when can I decompose ..." ?

Comment: @YemonChoi You are right. The vector $\mathbf{\alpha}$ and the weighted vector $\mathbf{h}$ are fixed at the start.

Answer (score 0):

As Alexandre Eremenko noted, the question is easy if you do not require independence.
The necessary condition  $\mathbb{E}\left[S\right]=\sum_{i=1}^nh_i\alpha_i$ noted by the OP is also sufficent (Edit: when one does not require an upper bound on the $X_i$.) If this condition holds, and $\mathbb{E}\left[S\right]>0$, then define
$$X_i=\frac{\alpha_i S}{\mathbb{E}\left[S\right]}\,.$$
These variables will satisfy $\sum_i h_iX_i=S$.

Edit: If one requires an upper bound of 1 on the $X_i$, then a sufficient condition (when the $\alpha_i$ are decreasing) is to also require
$$\alpha_1 \cdot \max S \le \mathbb{E}\left[S\right] \,.$$

Comment: Note that all $X_i$ should be on the interval $[0,1]$. Since the case of identical $\alpha_i$ is trivial, we can assume that $\alpha_1> \alpha_2\ge \cdots \ge \alpha_n $ without loss of generality. In your answer, $X_1=\frac{\alpha_1S}{\sum_{i=1}^n h_i\alpha_i}>S$ because $\sum_{i=1}^n h_i=1$ and all $h_i>0$. This is not acceptable.